# How can I query the top posts of different nodes?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**FIREBASE DATABASE**

```
-section1
   -post1
      -score: 2
-section2
   -post1
      -score: 3
   -post2
      -score: 1
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I query the posts of different nodes (section1 and section2) and order them by score as if the posts were part of the same node ?

Is there some kind of wildcard character I could use ?

---

**RESULT I WOULD LIKE TO GET OUT OF MY QUERY:**

```
-post1 (of section2)
-post1 (of section1)
-post2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no operation that will combine nodes out of two different branches in your tree. You will have to keep a normalized list of scores for this query.